# Magnific Popup not opening on the first click

Tags: jquery, popup, magnific-popup

I have been implementing magnific popup on my website here: http://entrepreneurshipdaily.com/tips/

The objective is to open the popup window every time a user clicks on the image or hyperlink on the right sidebar. I notice that when you first load the page and click the link, the popup does not open and instead the URL on the address bar changes to suffix a /#test-form. I need to reload the page for the popup to appear.

You may not encounter this if you click on the image before the page is completely loaded. Any idea what's causing this problem?

Codes:

Header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://entrepreneurshipdaily.com/tips/wp-includes/css/magnific-popup.css">
```

Footer:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://entrepreneurshipdaily.com/tips/wp-includes/js/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
```

Body of HTML:

```
<a class="popup-with-form" href="#test-form"><img src="http://entrepreneurshipdaily.com/tips/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/sidebar-cover.png" style="margin-left: 5px; border:none;" />

<!-- form itself-->
<form id="test-form" class="mfp-hide white-popup-block">
<div style="border:none;">
<h1 style="text-align:center; font-size:24px; font-weight:bold;">Enter Your Email Address To Get Free eBook</h1>

<div style="width:20%; float:left; padding:2px; ">
<img src="http://entrepreneurshipdaily.com/tips/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/lightbox-cover.png" style="border:none; width:90%; " />
</div>
<div style="width:80%; float:right; margin-left:10px;">
<fieldset style="border:0;">

<p style="color:#c0504d; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; font-size:26px; ">"How To Find Your First Customers"</p>

<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
#mc_embed_signup{background:#fff; clear:left; font:14px Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; }
/* Add your own MailChimp form style overrides in your site stylesheet or in this style block.
   We recommend moving this block and the preceding CSS link to the HEAD of your HTML file. */
</style>
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="http://entrepreneurshipdaily.us6.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post?u=9e46f33d29448fe10da5e45c7&amp;id=32789775fb" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>

<div class="mc-field-group">
<label for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address </label>
<input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL">
</div>
<div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
<div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
<div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
</div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
<div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_9e46f33d29448fe10da5e45c7_32789775fb" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
<div class="clear"><input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button"></div>
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var fnames = new Array();var ftypes = new Array();fnames[0]='EMAIL';ftypes[0]='email';
try {
var jqueryLoaded=jQuery;
jqueryLoaded=true;
} catch(err) {
var jqueryLoaded=false;
}
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
if (!jqueryLoaded) {
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js';
head.appendChild(script);
if (script.readyState && script.onload!==null){
    script.onreadystatechange= function () {
          if (this.readyState == 'complete') mce_preload_check();
    }    
}
}

var err_style = '';
try{
err_style = mc_custom_error_style;
} catch(e){
err_style = '#mc_embed_signup input.mce_inline_error{border-color:#6B0505;}   #mc_embed_signup div.mce_inline_error{margin: 0 0 1em 0; padding: 5px 10px; background-color:#6B0505; font-weight: bold; z-index: 1; color:#fff;}';
}
var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var style= document.createElement('style');
style.type= 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet) {
style.styleSheet.cssText = err_style;
} else {
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(err_style));
}
head.appendChild(style);
setTimeout('mce_preload_check();', 250);

var mce_preload_checks = 0;
function mce_preload_check(){
if (mce_preload_checks>40) return;
mce_preload_checks++;
try {
    var jqueryLoaded=jQuery;
} catch(err) {
    setTimeout('mce_preload_check();', 250);
    return;
}
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://downloads.mailchimp.com/js/jquery.form-n-validate.js';
head.appendChild(script);
try {
    var validatorLoaded=jQuery("#fake-form").validate({});
} catch(err) {
    setTimeout('mce_preload_check();', 250);
    return;
}
mce_init_form();
}
function mce_init_form(){
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
  var options = { errorClass: 'mce_inline_error', errorElement: 'div', onkeyup:  function(){}, onfocusout:function(){}, onblur:function(){}  };
  var mce_validator = $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").validate(options);
  $("#mc-embedded-subscribe-form").unbind('submit');//remove the validator so we can get into beforeSubmit on the ajaxform, which then calls the validator
  options = { url: 'http://entrepreneurshipdaily.us6.list-manage1.com/subscribe/post-json?u=9e46f33d29448fe10da5e45c7&id=32789775fb&c=?', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                beforeSubmit: function(){
                    $('#mce_tmp_error_msg').remove();
                    $('.datefield','#mc_embed_signup').each(
                        function(){
                            var txt = 'filled';
                            var fields = new Array();
                            var i = 0;
                            $(':text', this).each(
                                function(){
                                    fields[i] = this;
                                    i++;
                                });
                            $(':hidden', this).each(
                                function(){
                                    var bday = false;
                                    if (fields.length == 2){
                                        bday = true;
                                        fields[2] = {'value':1970};//trick birthdays into having years
                                    }
                                    if ( fields[0].value=='MM' && fields[1].value=='DD' && (fields[2].value=='YYYY' || (bday && fields[2].value==1970) ) ){
                                        this.value = '';
                                    } else if ( fields[0].value=='' && fields[1].value=='' && (fields[2].value=='' || (bday && fields[2].value==1970) ) ){
                                        this.value = '';
                                    } else {
                                        if (/\[day\]/.test(fields[0].name)){
                                            this.value = fields[1].value+'/'+fields[0].value+'/'+fields[2].value;                                           
                                        } else {
                                            this.value = fields[0].value+'/'+fields[1].value+'/'+fields[2].value;
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                        });
                    $('.phonefield-us','#mc_embed_signup').each(
                        function(){
                            var fields = new Array();
                            var i = 0;
                            $(':text', this).each(
                                function(){
                                    fields[i] = this;
                                    i++;
                                });
                            $(':hidden', this).each(
                                function(){
                                    if ( fields[0].value.length != 3 || fields[1].value.length!=3 || fields[2].value.length!=4 ){
                                        this.value = '';
                                    } else {
                                        this.value = 'filled';
                                    }
                                });
                        });
                    return mce_validator.form();
                }, 
                success: mce_success_cb
            };
  $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').ajaxForm(options);


});
}
function mce_success_cb(resp){
$('#mce-success-response').hide();
$('#mce-error-response').hide();
if (resp.result=="success"){
    $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
    $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(resp.msg);
    $('#mc-embedded-subscribe-form').each(function(){
        this.reset();
    });
} else {
    var index = -1;
    var msg;
    try {
        var parts = resp.msg.split(' - ',2);
        if (parts[1]==undefined){
            msg = resp.msg;
        } else {
            i = parseInt(parts[0]);
            if (i.toString() == parts[0]){
                index = parts[0];
                msg = parts[1];
            } else {
                index = -1;
                msg = resp.msg;
            }
        }
    } catch(e){
        index = -1;
        msg = resp.msg;
    }
    try{
        if (index== -1){
            $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
            $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);            
        } else {
            err_id = 'mce_tmp_error_msg';
            html = '<div id="'+err_id+'" style="'+err_style+'"> '+msg+'</div>';

            var input_id = '#mc_embed_signup';
            var f = $(input_id);
            if (ftypes[index]=='address'){
                input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index]+'-addr1';
                f = $(input_id).parent().parent().get(0);
            } else if (ftypes[index]=='date'){
                input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index]+'-month';
                f = $(input_id).parent().parent().get(0);
            } else {
                input_id = '#mce-'+fnames[index];
                f = $().parent(input_id).get(0);
            }
            if (f){
                $(f).append(html);
                $(input_id).focus();
            } else {
                $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
                $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);
            }
        }
    } catch(e){
        $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').show();
        $('#mce-'+resp.result+'-response').html(msg);
    }
}
}

</script>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
</fieldset>
</div>
</div>
</form>

<!-- link that opens popup -->
<div style="color:#269115; font-weight:bold; text-align: center; line-height: normal;  ">
Click here to grab a free copy of the ebook: <br /> <br />"How To Get Your First Customers" </div></a>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Sorry..Have added them now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your JavaScript code lacks the dom ready function:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
```

In this JsFiddle it works perfectly. And I see you're adding two jquery libraries in your code, one embedded and other auto added by javascript.

https://jsfiddle.net/netvicious/vygrgtef/